# Is FCM device token the same in debug and release apk?

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in React Native. In the debug mode, I can obtain FCM device token and successfully send push notification, however, on the release version I receive error “not registered” or "MismatchSenderId". Shouldn’t they be the same in both? Does having two projects in Firebase Console with same bundle id create conflict? In my case there is no issue in IOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no difference between the device token you get for debug and for release mode. If you're having problems, that's likely coming from somewhere else.

If you want people to help troubleshoot the problem, I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).